# Explicitly clear/reset a nested TensorFlow Graph scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I'm using a bunch of functions from OpenAI [baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/deepq) for Reinforcement Learning. In those functions, policy nets are initialised using statements like:

```
with tf.variable_scope('deepq', reuse=True):
    ...
    return output
```

The problem is that the pointer to the output of those networks gets returned while still inside the scope, which means that when accessing those functions from another .py file I am still inside those scopes.

Basically I want to run a first function `train_policy(output_dir)` that trains the net and dumps the checkpoint to disk using `tf.Saver()`.
Next, I run a function `run_policy(output_dir)` that reinitializes the same tf Graph and loads it's pretrained values using the checkpoint dir.

Right now, when I try this, I get a ValueError:
*`"Variable deepq/... already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?"`* because at the point of running the second function, I'm still in the scope defined by the first.. I checked the [code](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/deepq/build_graph.py) from OpenAI baselines (very nested code, hard to see everything that's going on), and **reuse is already set to True**.

So I tried doing something like:

`tf.get_default_session().close()` followed by:

`tf.reset_default_graph()`

after the first function call. (I don't need the session to remain active since I'm dumping everything to disk)

But this gives me errors because I'm still inside a nested graph scope and so I can't reset the default graph... (see eg [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11121))

Alternatively I tried things like:

```
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().__exit__()
```

or

```
tf.name_scope('deepq').__exit__()
```

but the exit() function needs a whole bunch of args I don't know how to get... (and I can't find good [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) on how to use this function).

My current solution is to run these functions in separate subprocesses in Python (and let the garbage collector do all the work), but this doensn't feel like a satisfactory solution..

Any ideas on how to deal with this? Ideally I'd need something like: **`tf.clear_all_graphs_and_sessions()`**

Answer (score 3):

Ait one solution is indeed to reset the default graph:
I simply wrap every function call in a new default graph object like this:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  train_policy(output_dir)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
   run_policy(output_dir)

...
```

This way the default graph simply gets reinitialised empty and you can load whatever is in the checkpoint file. (Inside every function I also close the default session before returning).

Comment: What's `with tf.Graph().as_default():` actually doing?  Does that make a fresh tensorflow graph for every operation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do your work in another default graph:

```py
with tf.get_default_graph().as_default():
  with tf.variable_scope('deepq', reuse=False):
    v = tf.get_variable('v', shape=[])
    print(v.name, v.graph)

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
      v = tf.get_variable('v', shape=[])
      print(v.name, v.graph)
```

Output:

```
deepq/v:0 <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f61adaa6390>
v:0 <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f61460abbd0>
```

Comment: Hmm this doesnt work for me.. I'm basically running two functions: path= create_initial_agent(output_dir, initial_target_score) and
generate_train_data(path). Where the first one saves the trained policy network checkpoint to disk and the second creates an identical graph and restores the variables from that checkpoint. But if I create different graphscopes then the saver.restore(sess, path) doesn't work...

Comment: Can you provide the details? As you can see, the graph is reset

Comment: The problem is that my tf.Saver() stores the graph names as "deepq/v:0". So when it tries to restore those in a new session, there is no "deepq:v:0" defined in the active graph because it's now called "v:0"

Comment: I see. So, you can add `with tf.variable_scope('deepq', reuse=False)` as well

Comment: I can't because the `generate_train_data()` function creates a new graph definition (the same as the first one) so when I encaps it in a new variable_scope I get a nested scope 'deepq/deepq/v:0'. Feels awkward that there really is no way to completely reset all graphs/sessions in TF..

Comment: OK. It's better you include all this into your question, ideally with links to the source code.